# I aborted Smart Merge in Android Studio, it rolled back all the changes I made since pulling the branch?

Tags: android-studio, data-loss

I tried merging a branch, then realized the changes were substantial enough to just create a new branch, so I clicked `Abort...` and the changes were "rolled back to before the smart merge". Now all the changes and new files I made are gone. Is there any way to get them back?

Try - Abort smart merge and continue working with my changed files
Expected - All my files to not change at all
Reality - Plz help